# How to load large list of JSON files from local directory into react app

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have been given 100+ JSON files which I need to display locally in a react app. I'm able to load one file at a time using the `fetch()` function, but I'm not sure how to load all of the files.

I've considered getting a list of all of the files and then doing a `fetch()` on the list, but the issue is that I cannot access the list of files in the directory.

I read that I could use `fs` but it seems like that won't work in the browser. ex: I've tried:

```
  var fs = require('fs');

  var files = fs.readdirSync('../app/components/data/');
```

but this throws the error: `fs.readdirSync is not a function`. I'm open to different approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are small, one option would be to merge them all into one large JSON array in one file and `fetch()` that. If you don't mind load times taking a bit of a hit, you could even import or `require()` the JSON file from your application code, including its contents in your JS bundle.

However, if the files are big, you're probably better off creating a 'manifest' file which describes the contents and locations of the other files. It wouldn't be too hard to write a script to store all the files in that directory in an array in an `index.json`. From there, you could `fetch()` the index from the browser, and then `fetch()` each file individually.